# kube-controller-manager outputs an error "cannot change NodeName"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, coreos

I use kubernetes on AWS with CoreOS & flannel VLAN network.
(followed this guide https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html)
k8s version is `1.4.6`.

And I have the following node-exporter daemon-set.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: node-exporter
  labels:
    app: node-exporter
    tier: monitor
    category: platform
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-exporter
        tier: monitor
        category: platform
      name: node-exporter
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: prom/node-exporter:0.12.0
        name: node-exporter
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9100
          hostPort: 9100
          name: scrape
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPID: true
```

When I run this, kube-controller-manager outputs an error repeatedly as below:

```
E1117 18:31:23.197206       1 endpoints_controller.go:513]
Endpoints "node-exporter" is invalid:
[subsets[0].addresses[0].nodeName: Forbidden: Cannot change NodeName for 172.17.64.5 to ip-172-17-64-5.ec2.internal,
subsets[0].addresses[1].nodeName: Forbidden: Cannot change NodeName for 172.17.64.6 to ip-172-17-64-6.ec2.internal,
subsets[0].addresses[2].nodeName: Forbidden: Cannot change NodeName for 172.17.80.5 to ip-172-17-80-5.ec2.internal,
subsets[0].addresses[3].nodeName: Forbidden: Cannot change NodeName for 172.17.80.6 to ip-172-17-80-6.ec2.internal,
subsets[0].addresses[4].nodeName: Forbidden: Cannot change NodeName for 172.17.96.6 to ip-172-17-96-6.ec2.internal]
```

Just for information, despite from this error message, node_exporter is accessible on e.g.) `172-17-96-6:9100` . My nodes are in a private network including k8s master.

But these logs are output too many and makes it difficult to see other logs by eyes from our log console. Could I see how to resolve this error?

Because I built my k8s cluster from scratch, `cloud-provider=aws` flag was not  activated at first and I recently turned it on, but not sure if it's related to this issue.

Comment: If you're just getting started, I recommend `kops`. If you need CoreOS, you can try `kube-aws`.

Comment: Unfortunately we already running the cluster on production and it has worked very well until this happens. I actually used CoreOS's multi-node script, which is one of their recommendation with `kube-aws` . I want to move `kubeadm` when it becomes mature, but it's different topic from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks this is caused by my another manifest file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-exporter
  labels:
    app: node-exporter
    tier: monitor
    category: platform
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: scrape
    port: 9100
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: node-exporter
  type: ClusterIP
```

I thought this is necessary to expose node-exporter daemon-set above, but it could rather introduce some sort of conflict when I set `hostNetwork: true` in a daemon-set (actually, a pod) manifest. I'm not 100% certain though, after I delete this service the error disappears while I can still access to `172-17-96-6:9100` from outside of the k8s cluster.

I just followed by this post when setting prometheus and node-exporter,
https://coreos.com/blog/prometheus-and-kubernetes-up-and-running.html

in case others face with the same problem, I'm leaving my comment here.